# Shouldn't this piece be written in 6/8?

Tags: rhythm, interpretation

Both my eyes and my [ears](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWKwQ2gBRc0) feel that this piece (Ludovico Einaudi - Stella del mattino) should be written in 6/8, not in 3/4. Am I wrong ? Should I care?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's 3/4 or 6/8. Why not bring out the ambiguity and leave the listener guessing?

Comment: Note, to my mind this asks (or hints at) one very objective question *about* subjective perception: "**Why** do I hear 6/8 rather than 3/4?" The answer has a lot to do with the topography of the arpeggiated pattern. To avoid getting the question closed as opinion-based, you might want to edit to emphasize that aspect.

Comment: @PiedPiper "Stick to ambiguity" might be a valid answer. My problem is that I don't see the ambiguity, I think/hear/play those measures in unambiguous 6/8. I'm asking if I should strive to work on that

Comment: If you can't hear the 3/4 then you need to work on it until you can.

Comment: When you can hear the 3/4, it's time to work on 7/8.

Comment: I could play this extract as 3/4 or as 6/8 - either would make sense and you wouldn't mistake one for the other listening to me. It all depends where you put the less stressed accents.

Answer (score 3):

Listened to your video (admittedly with mediocre ear buds and at lower than maximum volume) for the entire first page and you're right - every 3rd 8th note is emphasized throughout, not every 2nd 8th note, and so I'd also notate this piece in **6/8 time**. The left hand wasn't enough to contradict the every-3rd-8th-note accent or pulse.

I later listened to the entire piece and *still* found it to be entirely in 6/8 time. Perhaps unusually, not a single 3/4 measure is sneaked in (although the last 8th note of some measures is emphasized).

As an amateur transcriber who's learned the hard way not to trust others' transcriptions, I care what meter music is notated in - and if you want to reproduce the recording, so should you.

Answer (score 3):

Listening for the first time, it came over more as 12/8 time. Or more specifically, each of the two bars written as one, so each second bar 1st beat was slightly less emphasised than the 1st beat of the odd numbered bars.

The whole point of 3/4 instead of 6/8 is the *emphasis* within the bar. With 3/4, there will often be 3 emphasis points, on each crotchet, while 6/8 will have two emphases, on the 1st and 4th quavers. Otherwise, writing it as in the example posted gives no clues as to how each bar gets any emphases. But surely the point of writing out the dots is so that any reader can reproduce the piece as the writer intended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apart from the last line, it falls glibly into 6/8.   Or, rather more interestingly, into 3/4, the pulse contrasting with the obvious note groupings.

The composer has instructed you to feel it the second way.   Obey him.

Comment: Ironically, I assume the video performance is by the composer himself, and as noted, he makes little effort to whack out three big beats; if anything, he seems to be making a Reich/Glass effort to keep all the eighths equal—in which case, the arpeggiated pattern does lead one into hearing 6/8.

Comment: I personally suspect that the sheet music is from a separate transcriber not approved or endorsed by the composer.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say until measure 33 the first impression of this would be 6/8, starting at 33 this is the case anymore. With more contemporary composer there is a development that time signature become nothing but a thing of organisation. There are composers who write anything in 4/4, like Ligeti and suchlike (although these composers usually do not write this kind of pop music).